# Inserir borda colorida em imagem que é capa

Tags: php, css

Estou tentando destacar uma div que está com uma imagem de capa com uma borda usando `css`, mas não estou conseguindo.
Faço um loop para mostrar as imagens mas o usuário não consegue saber qual imagem é a capa, a imagem abaixo mostra como está o meu script.

```
<li class="span3">
  <div class="thumbnail">     
    <div class="caption">           
    <p> 
        <button name="btnexcluir" id_banner="<?php echo $id_banner; ?>" id_banner_foto="<?php echo $id_banner_foto; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" >Excluir</button> 
        <button name="btncapa" id_banner="<?php echo $id_banner; ?>" id_banner_foto="<?php echo $id_banner_foto; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >Capa</button>       
    </p>            
    </div>      
    <img src="<?php echo "../".$row_rcImagens['caminho_thumbs']; ?>" />
  </div>              
</li>
```

Tentei fazer um `if` verificando a condição da variável `$capa` = 1 e aplicando o css.

A imagem mostra o que estou tentando fazer.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer algo baseado nesse post:
[Exemplo de Borda](http://jsfiddle.net/a8zregpb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplique um css *inline* na div que vc quer a borda colorida:

```
<div <?php if($capa == 1){ ?>style="border-color: #f30;"<?php } ?>></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Dvdsamm, resolveu o meu problema, valeu.